# Django mail_admins not sending an email

Tags: python, django

i have tried using send_mail and it work properly (its html showing value '1') but When i access localhost:8000/emailAdmins , its showing a 'none' word in html, please help me why my mail_admins doesn't work

My setting

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

ADMINS = [
    ('myname' , 'myemail@gmail.com'),
]
```

My url

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from app1 import views as myapp

urlpatterns = [

     url(r'^emailAdmins/',myapp.sendAdminsEmail,name='emailAdmins'),
]
```

My view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

def sendAdminsEmail(request):
    res = mail_admins('my subject', 'site is going down',)
    return HttpResponse('%s' %res)
```

Comment: have you set your variable  `EMAIL_BACKEND`?

Comment: this is my email backend, EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' , i just recently add it but it still doesnt work

Comment: Did you check in your terminal that the email got printed? This is the place where the email goes if you have that configuration.

Comment: `mail_admins()` doesn't return anything - hence why you get `None`. That doesn't mean the email wasn't sent. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/core/mail/#mail_admins

Comment: oh yeah, i've got the email, sorry, my bad , thanks for the replies imiguelvargasf & solarissmoke

Answer (score 0):

Add this line with your email configuration it worked for me

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```